# How to confirm delivery status when using amazonSNS mobile push?

Tags: amazon-sns

I'm using AmazonSNS to send push messages to IOS device. I have got the publishResult with a messageID. Is there any way I can use this messageID to check the delivery status ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Amazon just added support for message delivery status: [Application Attributes for Message Delivery Status](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-msg-status.html?ref_=pe_411040_132389510). It works in conjunction with [Cloudwatch Logs](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cloudwatch).

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to confirm that a message has been delivered.  However, it looks like there is a way to receive an event when a message *fails* to be delivered.   Check out the EventDeliveryFailure here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetPlatformApplicationAttributes.html

Maybe if you ask the SNS folks over at the AWS forums for an EventDeliveryCompleted you might be able to use that.

Comment: lol @ downvote.  If you don't like the answer, go down vote Amazon.

Comment: I tried this thing, doesn't seems to work. I created a topic, assigned the topicARN, send a message with wrong token and an oversized message, in both the cases it threw AmazonServiceException but the message was not published on the topic about the failure.

Comment: @Pankaj Singhal: Well, it sounds like those are publish failures, not delivery failures.  Delivery failures occur if a message which was successfully published cannot be delivered.  In your case, you have the exception thrown by the publish call and can handle that there.