# How to get delivery report info on AWS SNS using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using the AWS php SDK to send SNS messages. I am using APNS. I have followed the SDK examples, no problems there. Most of my messages are getting sent, but some appear to be failing. According to the SNS doc, if I get a message ID back - which I am every single time - then the message has been saved to the queue. How do I get more detailed information about these failed messages? The messages are obviously failing in the attempt to send between AWS and APNS.

```
$result = $client->publish(array(
    'TopicArn' => 'string',
    'TargetArn' => 'string',
    // Message is required
    'Message' => 'string',
    'Subject' => 'string',
    'MessageStructure' => 'string',
));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to confirm delivery statue when using amazonSNS mobile push?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651315/how-to-confirm-delivery-statue-when-using-amazonsns-mobile-push)