# AWS SNS push notification clarification

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have few doubts regarding sending SNS Push Notifications.

1) I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845984/how-to-send-extra-parameters-in-payload-via-amazon-sns-push-notification) stackoverflow discussion where we can set sound for APNS. But how we do it for GCM ?

2) How to configure **no sound** alert ?

3) Is it possible to set sound for each Endpoint in PHP while creating them ? I just want to know this so that while sending message I can send to those with sound enabled and to those disabled while sending it with topicARN.

4) I referred [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/msg-status-topics.html#msg-status-sdk) document for getting the delivery status of push notification as logs in cloudwatch. Is there any API to retrieve the delivery status of those endpoints which failed to receive in PHP ?

Comment: Do you want to create custom sound alert for each endpoint arn?

Answer (score 2):

For GCM, you can do like this:

```
$send = $sns->publish(array(
         'TargetArn' => $EndpointArn, //   to send notification to single user
         'MessageStructure' => 'json',
         'Message' => json_encode(array(
                     'default' => '',
                      'APNS' => json_encode(array(
                                      'aps' => array(
                                      'alert' => 'message to topic',
                                      'sound'=> 'default',
                                      'badge'=> 1
                                     ),
                                'userid' => '1'
                            )),
                     'GCM' => json_encode(array(
                            'data' => array(
                                'alert' => 'message to topic',
                                'userid' => '1'
                                ),
                            ))
                        ))
                ));
```

Do you want to create a custom sound alert for each endpoint arn?

For **4th point** refer this links:
1) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-msg-status.html?ref_=pe_411040_132389510

2) [How to confirm delivery status when using amazonSNS mobile push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651315/how-to-confirm-delivery-status-when-using-amazonsns-mobile-push)

Comment: Like APNS we are not setting anything for GCM. What if I dont want to set any sound ?

Comment: @Reaching-Out sound handling is from Android side.

Comment: @Reaching-Out ok.. did you find any useful?

Comment: no. I have tried all these documents and devised my own method. But what I'm looking or is a straight cut solution.

Comment: @Reaching-Out sound notifications will be managed from device only